# Is there a difference between the number most closest to zero and zero

Tags: analysis

Let's call the number most closest to zero x. Hence if any number subtracted  by 0 is equal to the number itself..

x - 0 = x
meaning that the answer would be the number that's most closest to zero..

Im confused with that if there's no difference between the number that's most closest to zero and 0 , how can there be an accumulation in the number system as the difference would be 0

Comment: The number closest to a number $a$ is the number $a$ itself. For any $a$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no number closest to zero (if we are only considering non-zero numbers) If we had a number that was "closest", call it $x$, then $x/2$ is even closer to $0$, a contradiction.